# scripts-webpack-plugin✖ ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: '/node_modules/jquery.flot.spline/jquery.flot.spline.js'

Tags: webpack, angular6

Getting this error while running Angular 6 on production.

91% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin✖ ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/client-admin/node_modules/jquery.flot.spline/jquery.flot.spline.js'

Is there any possible Solutions?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by making minor changes in angular.json file

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.css",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 ],
 "scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
 ]
```